# "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar)" why?

Tags: java, maven, jar

So I was trying to use **Maven** on a random project to check how it works, and when I try to build the executable **jar** in **IntelliJ** it gives the error:

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) on project lab0_ggcd: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar for parameter addClassPath: Cannot find 'addClassPath' in class org.apache.maven.archiver.ManifestConfiguration`

I have also tried removing the **.m2/repository** like many people says but it doesn't work.

My **pom.xml** looks like:

```
....
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClassPath>true</addClassPath>
                        <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>
                            ggcd.Main
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the project structure is:

[image]

**Main class** only has a **System.out.println**.

Comment: do you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<addClassPath>` should be `<addClasspath>`